# is there a lodash function that is a combination of _.map() and _.filter()?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a set of div elements:

```
<div class="myDiv" key="default">Default Val</div>
<div class="myDiv" key="default">Default Val2</div>
<div class="myDiv" key="myVal-1">Value 1</div>
<div class="myDiv" key="myVal-2">Value 2</div>
<div class="myDiv" key="myVal-3">Value 3</div>
```

And I want to collect all 'key' attributes except those with 'default' value into an array.
I know I can use _.each() for that, but is there a lodash function that is a combination of _.map() and _.filter()? In other words I need something like this:

```
arr = _.func($('.myDiv'), (el) => {
    // collects truthy values and ignores falsy ones
    return $(el).attr('key') == 'default' ? $(el).attr('key') : false;
});
arr // => ["myVal-1", "myVal-2", "myVal-3"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `map` *and* `filter`:

```
arr = _.filter(
  _.map(
    $('.myDiv'),
    el => $(el).attr('key')
  ),
  key => key != 'default'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `reduce` where you can define anything in a loop. But it doesn't necessary mean it's easier to read.

```
arr = _.reduce($('.myDiv'), (result, el) => {
  const key = $(el).attr('key');
  if (key !== 'default') result.push(key);
  return result;
}, []);
```